# How are clans matched up for war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When a war search is started, can anyone do anything to determine who the matching clan will be? I've noticed the other clan keeps having considerably higher level Town Halls. Step 5 of [this wiki how article](http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Successful-Clan-in-Clash-of-Clans) makes it sound like you can choose who you go to war with

> Start wars that you can win. The most important thing about being
>   leader of a clan is managing the clan wars appropriately. If your clan
>   gets smashed, many members will leave and find another clan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee you will be matched against a weaker clan, but there is a way to guarantee the match is fair. I found this discussion - http://www.allclash.com/clan-war-matchmaking/ - of how clan matchmaking works. The usable takeaway from this article is that the clan matchmaking algorithm tries very hard at first to find equal clans and gradually becomes less and less picky as the search goes on. So if you want a very even war match-up, run clan matchmaking for only a short time before cancelling it. You can just start over again every so often until you're matched up.

Comment: yes, it took a really long time to run and now we've got all t.h. 8 and higher

Comment: I presume this will also lower your chances of getting an easy game against a clan much weaker than you?